# How to import customers in magento-2 using csv?

Tags: customer, import, magento2, csv, importexport

Currently i am working on magento-2 .I have imported products successfully. Now i want to be import customers . I dont have any demo csv for import customers .

Answer (score 3):

You can check the test files which will give you an example of the data needed to import customers. Under:

`app/code/Magento/CustomerImportExport/Test/Unit/Model/Import/_files/customer_composite_prepare_row_for_db.csv`

Also am adding the file if for some reason it is not included.

```
"email","_website","_store","confirmation","created_at","created_in","disable_auto_group_change","dob","firstname","gender","group_id","lastname","middlename","password_hash","prefix","reward_update_notification","reward_warning_notification","rp_token","rp_token_created_at","store_id","suffix","taxvat","website_id","password","_address_city","_address_country","_address_street","_address_default_billing_","_address_default_shipping_"
```